# If a negative value print "0" instead

Tags: php, negative-number

I have a simple php scrip to converts a csv file into a different layout which works fine, but I want to add a rule that if the value is negative then output 0 instead.
Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do it ( code below with the line where the rule to be applied marked)

Thanks

```
<?php

function twoDecs($num_in)
{
    $split = explode('.', $num_in);
    if(!isset($split[1]))
        $num_out = $num_in . '.00';
    else{
        if(strlen($split[1])<2)
            $num_out = $split[0] . '.' . $split[1] . '0';
        else
            $num_out = $split[0] . '.' . $split[1];
    }

    return $num_out;
}

function array_to_csv($array_in)
{
    $csv_content = 'sku;qty;special_price;price;is_in_stock
';
    $lines = explode('
', $array_in);

    for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++)
    {
        $line = explode(',', $lines[$i]);
        if(trim($line[1])!='')
        {
            $csv_content .= trim($line[1]) . ';';
            $csv_content .= trim($line[8]) . ';';  <----- line where rule to be added
            $csv_content .= twoDecs(trim($line[6])) . ';';
            $csv_content .= twoDecs(trim($line[7])) . ';';
            $csv_content .= '1' . '
';
        }
        unset($line);
    }

    $now = date('YmdHis');
    file_put_contents('files/ProductUpdateRF.csv', $csv_content);
    echo '<a href="files/ProductUpdateRF.csv"> Download reformatted CSV here. </a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You can use `max($var,0)`

Comment: Is `$line[8]` stores that value, that can be negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out:

```
$csv_content .= (intval(trim($line[8])) < 0 ? "0" : trim($line[8])) . ';';
```

This uses the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) which is a shorthand `if()`.

Comment: @Nidhoegger I've edited your answer to add a link to the documentation as [code-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/246338)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
$csv_content .= max(trim($line[8]), 0).';';
```

This uses [Max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) which returns the highest value. In this case, if the first parameter's value is less than zero (2nd parameter), MAX will return zero

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the code readable and to solve your problem you can use the [ternary (shorthand) operator ?:](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
$csv_content .= (float) $line[8] < 0 ? 0 : trim($line[8]) . ';';
```

Comment: this broke the php page (would not load)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: @DavidPostill teached the lesson (however, there is so little to explain, just code basically)

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($line[8]<0)
    $csv_content .= 0 ';'; 
else 
    $csv_content .= trim($line[8]) . ';';
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged in SO so, could you explain how the code solves OP's question.

Comment: we are checking if that line[8] value is less than 0(negative) if so then display this as 0 other wise appropriate value will display. that is what d original requirement.. ignore syntax.